# spring websocket not receiving messages from react

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I have a spring application that needs to receive messages using a websocket.

**Config.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class Config implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/simulator").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/endpoint");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
}
```

**MessageController.java**

```
@Controller
public class MessageController {


@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/endpoint/greeting")
public ResponseEntity<?> getContent(@RequestBody Message message) {
        JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
        jo.put("isLiked", "Yes");
        System.out.println("here");
        System.out.println(message.getName());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(jo, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

**Message.java**

```
public class Message {

    private String name;

    public Message(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

I also have a simple React.js app that has two buttons "connct" and "send".
When you click on "connect", a connection with Spring is made and it is successful (I get data in the console about a successful connection).
But when I click on "send", I get information that json has been sent, but Spring does not register it in any way (neither displays messages to the console, nor sends a response, nor enters data into the "endpoint/greeting" channel)

**App.js**

```
import './index.css';
import SockJS from "sockjs-client"
import Stomp from 'stompjs'
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

function App() {

let stompClient;

      const connect = () => {
      const socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/simulator");
      stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
      stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
      console.log("Connected " + frame);
      stompClient.subscribe("http://localhost:8080/endpoint/greeting", function (greeting) {
      console.log("hi" + JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
      });
      });
      };

      const sendSomething = () => {
      stompClient.send("http://localhost:8080/hello",{}, JSON.stringify({"name":"John"}));
      };

return (
      <>
      <button onClick={connect}>Connect</button>
      <button onClick={sendSomething}>Send</button>
      </>

);
}

export default App;
```

I've been having this problem for a few days now. But I still can't find the answer
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are missing @SubscribeMapping in your controller. I took the reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999004/subscribemapping-vs-messagemapping)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first issue, there is an attempt to send a message to the "/hello" endpoint. However, it appears that the endpoint lacks the necessary configuration to receive messages. To rectify this, you should modify your MessageController class by adding a specific annotation that enables message reception for the "/hello" endpoint.

Moving on to the second problem, you are trying to send a message with the body {"name":"John"}. Unfortunately, the Message class does not have a corresponding "name" property. To resolve this issue, you need to adjust the message body accordingly.

Lastly, it seems that you are attempting to subscribe to the "/endpoint/greeting" channel. However, this channel is not currently configured to send messages. To enable message transmission, you should make the necessary configuration changes for the "/endpoint/greeting" channel.

If you require additional information or resources, you can refer to the following sources, which have been provided by you:

1. GitHub repository: MyRepo_Virtusa-Boardcast-Chat-Server (by Ajithaj23)
   Link: [MyRepo_Virtusa-Boardcast-Chat-Server](https://github.com/Ajithaj23/MyRepo_Virtusa-Boardcast-Chat-Server)
2. Blog post on dodop-blog.tistory.com
   Title: "Topic" (written by you)
   Link: [Blog post](https://dodop-blog.tistory.com/227)
3. GitHub repository: Thesis_Masters_Project (by ClintonProjects)
   Link: [Thesis_Masters_Project](https://github.com/ClintonProjects/Thesis_Masters_Project)